# Failed in Populating a WPF chart from DB data

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I want to create a bar chart and i am following the tutorial

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/bar-chart-in-wpf/

but the bar chart failed to populate with the database data.
here is my code

> chart.xaml

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
        <local:FreqChart x:Key="frequency" />
    </Grid.Resources>

        <DVC:Chart Name="fChart" Width="400" Height="250" Background="LightSteelBlue">
            <DVC:Chart.Series>
                <DVC:PieSeries Title="Frequency Chart" ItemsSource="{StaticResource frequency}"
                     IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=name}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=occurence}">
                </DVC:PieSeries>
            </DVC:Chart.Series>
        </DVC:Chart>
    </Grid>
```

C# collection from where the chart is populating

```
class category
{
    public string name;
    public int occurence;
}

class FreqChart : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<category> 
{
    public FreqChart()
    {
        DataTable dt= DB.FrequencyRecordSet(); // this DataTable is populated from database
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Add(new category { name = row[0].ToString(), occurence = int.Parse(row[1].ToString()) });
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to first work out where the problem is. We don't have access to your tools or full code. Have you set a break point to work out if your FrequencyRecordSet method is returning any data. Also, I don't see how you are loading this data to the view.

Comment: Yeh i have check the FrequencyRecordSet returns accurate dataset,  I create a resource Frequency and bind it to the PieSeries using the ItensSource property

Comment: How are you loading the data to the itemssource of the control?

Comment: I created a resource Frequency and bind it to the PieSeries using the ItensSource property